# using Sesame to process a SPARQL/XML stream (output from Vitruoso)

Tags: java, sesame, virtuoso

I have a SPARQL/XML results stream (happens to be coming back from a Virtuoso server), and I would like to process the results as they stream back from the http connection.

Sesame has a very nice library for doing this - assuming you are speaking full Sesame it's easy and I have that implemented.  But instead of having Sesame generate the request I am doing it over a different HTTP connection that doesn't speak full Sesame, and I don't know of an immediate way to make the Sesame library do that.

With Sesame you can use a `RepositoryConnection` create a `TupleQuery` with `.prepareTupleQuery` and then pass `.evaluate` a solution handler (something that extends `TupleQueryResultHandlerBase`).

I'm assuming there are some classes under the hood where I could pass a solution handler and an `InputStream` to and let the Sesame classes take care of the parsing, buffering, and making the callback etc.  Certainly the code is in there, but I've been wading through the source for  hours and seem like I'm going in circles.

If there is another library or solution that fine too I'll gladly take the pointer, but I thought I would just take advantage of my other Sesame-related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sesame's [QueryResultIO](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/resultio/QueryResultIO.html) utility for this. Simplest way is to just let it parse the stream into a query result object. Like so:

```
InputStream in = ...;
TupleQueryResult result = QueryResultIO.parse(in, TupleQueryResultFormat.SPARQL);
```

The above is hardwired to create a result object. If you want more control over the processing, you can create a [TupleQueryResultParser](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/resultio/TupleQueryResultParser.html) object and assign it your own TupleQueryResultHandler implementation. Something like this:

```
TupleQueryResultParser parser = QueryResultIO.createParser(TupleQueryResultFormat.SPARQL);

TupleQueryResultHandler handler = new MyCustomStreamingResultHandler();
parser.setQueryResultHandler(handler);

parser.parseQueryResult(in);
```

Or like this, if you're working with an older version of Sesame (2.6 or older):

```
TupleQueryResultHandler handler = new MyCustomStreamingResultHandler();
parser.setTupleQueryResultHandler(handler);

parser.parse(in);
```

Sesame provides several stock implementation of `TupleQueryResultHandler`, but it's very straightforward to create your own as well if you wish to have full control over the parser output processing.

Comment: Thanks. Although I think there is a "typo" in your answer instead of parser.setQueryResultHandler it should be parser.setTupleQueryResultHandler.

Comment: Apparently edits have to be at least 6 characters - so I couldn't add just "Tuple" I had to add "(Edited)" to the bottom too. odd.

Comment: Sorry, but my original answer was actually correct. `setTupleQueryResultHandler` is deprecated, `setQueryResultHandler` is the recommended method. I'll add a ref to the Javadoc for you. Though by that logic my use of the `parse` method was also incorrect. Fixed now.

Comment: It looks like it was deprecated in 2.7?  There's still a lot of Sesame 2.6 code out there.  Looks like the newer one doesn't exist in 2.6, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true, so indeed if you are working with an older version of Sesame, you will need to use the older methods.